# Evaluate summation combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

In class recently an identity was mentioned, and I am unsure of how they got the solution. The equation is the following:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2^{2k}} \binom{n}{k} = 5^n$$

I know I have to use the binomial coefficients but the results I have been getting just don't seem correct. Any idea how this works out? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You can insert equations using the $ indicative. There's more info in the formatting help when typing a question or answer.

Comment: Try using the binomial formula on $(4+1)^n=(2^2+1)^n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! In the binomial theorem:

$$ (x + y)^n = \sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} x^j y^{n-j} $$

set $x = 4 = 2^2$ and $y = 1$. Done!

Comment: Thank you.I am wondering though, if I did not have 5^n how would I expand the left side (summation) to get to here?

Comment: Sometimes by luck, sometimes by guess and check. You really just spot the patterns. Also, show your appreciation by upvoting the answer.

Comment: I did upvote but as you can see I am new